# Integral with exponential and square root

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need help with the following indefinite integral:

$\int \sqrt{x^2-a^2} \,e^{b x} dx $

where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants. Thanks!

Comment: from where Comes that integral? i don't think that we can get a solution in elementary functions

Comment: Sonnhard, It showed up in a calculation. I tried several substitutions did not work.

Comment: i send it to Wolfram Alpha